# How to get JSON into JavaScript object array?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm stuck with getting the JSON below, generated in Spring Boot, into a JavaScript object array. Could you please help to solve?

### [image: JSON format from Spring Boot]

I'm using XMLHttpRequest. My JS looks like:

```
let evtObjt = [];

var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

request.onreadystatechange = function () {

   if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
      var data = JSON.parse(request.response); 
      console.log(data);

      evtObjt = data; 
   }                
}
request.open('GET', '/rest-view/events', true); 
request.send();
```

Regards

Murilo

Comment: It's already an array of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It's convenient for other members if you transcribe your source code into the question instead of posting a picture of it. Please consider the guidelines in asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi bad_coder, thank you for your tip but, in this case, I used image for two basic reasons: 1. The image isn't a source code, it's a console print for debugging insight only, as considered in the link you sent me for good/bad practices: "demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text." (stackoverflow). 2. The actual source code is in edditable format. Regards

Comment: Hi Simon Crane, thank you for your question. The problem was solved by ORunnals below. I couldn't get JSON into an object array because it was embedded. I had to go all the way through the events "data._embedded.events;" to access it. Now, it's working. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you might just need to change your assignment to fix it:

```
evtObjt = data._embedded.events;
```

This would assign the events array into the evtObjt. Hopefully that's what you were looking to do.

Comment: Hi ORunnals, that makes sense, but I'm getting this error in console : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined"

Comment: Brilliant! It works... Thank you very much ORunnals. Regards